# Pass parent scope variable to a directive as an attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'd like to build my own version of an Angular checkbox that uses ng-model. (Documentation here: [Checkbox in Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D))

I've built my button, but am not sure how to link it up to ng-model. [Here's a plunker of what I have so far](http://plnkr.co/edit/oy0dXu82DefIcYeoaghV?p=preview).

I want to be able to pass in an angular variable as an attribute like you can do with ng-model:

```
<fl-toggle text="change the boolean!" ng-model="theBoolean"></fl-toggle>
```

Then, in under "link" in the directive modify the variable by doing something like this (but this doesn't work)

```
link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
    elem.bind('mouseup', function() {
        if (attrs.ngModel === true) {
            attrs.ngModel = false;
        } else {
            attrs.ngModel = true;
        }
    });
}
```

I know that I could just use ng-click to accomplish the same result, but this feels more official. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model` actually has a controller associated with it, and you can require this in your directive using the following syntax:

```
{
  require:'ngModel'
  link:function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
     //ngModelCtrl will be passed in automatically
  }
}
```

This will pass in an instance of the [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) for use inside your directive. You can use it to manage the interaction between the model and the view.